# Direct Code Vs Library in android

Tags: java, android, static-libraries

Direct Coding Vs Library

Will using a library with the same code and functionality increase the size of the app when compared to the case when the code is directly written instead of calling a library

For example, consider the code for getting longitude and latitude values. If I put it in a library and attach that library to the project and call the methods present in it to get the values instead of writing the code directly, will doing so add to the size of the app. If doing so will not have any change in the size , then it would be useful to make such libraries and attach them to the projects whenever needed

thanks in advance

Comment: Please confirm we are talking about a JAVA android application here (as opposed to NDK C/C++ development)

Comment: @Elemental : Yes I am talking about Java android development.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib : I am sorry, I didn't get you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that if you use  Proguard as recommended by Google theoretically they should be the same sized APK.
Proguard should only use the classes from the libraries which are referenced to build the APK.

On top of that Proguard has other functionality to shrink the APK size. It is not without it's drawbacks though.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Note: Proguard is only used once you are ready for production.

Answer (score 0):

While this question needs more elaboration, and such a comparison will not give you 100% answer, usually using the libraries will give you a smaller application footprint.

Pure C library without OOP should give the best results.

Comment: :Thanks for the response.What I meant was  For example, consider the code for getting longitude and latitude values. If I put it in a library and attach that library to the project and call the methods present in it to get the values instead of writing the code directly, will doing so add to the size of the app. If doing so will not have any change in the size , then it would be useful to make such libraries and attach them to the projects whenever needed.